# Fs createWriteStream has stopped working in heroku

Tags: jquery, node.js, npm, fs

I have a piece of code that creates a pdf out of jade using jade-pdf-redline.
Unfortunately it seemed to have suddenly stopped working in heroku. It worked before, and not I'm not sure what happened.

I did upgrade from fs to mz/fs but it still doesn't want to work.

```
fs.createReadStream('www/template/template.jade', {encoding: 'utf8'}, function(){})
        .pipe(jadepdf({
            locals: {
                "header": settingsDataParsed.header,
                "logo": settingsDataParsed.logo,
                "body": bodyShell,
                "footerEmail": settingsDataParsed.email,
                "footerNum": settingsDataParsed.footer,
            }
        }))
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path));
```